# mysqldmup with data only

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, insert

Is there a way to backup data using mysqldump --no-create-info ... where the inserts in the backup file will look like this:

```
insert into t1(col1, col2)values(val1,val2);
```

instead of

```
insert into t1 values(val1,val2);
```

The problem with the second way is that when the table structure changes, the insert will not work. With the first way, the table structure, e.g, one more column is added, will not affect the insert statement.

I have to use the mysqldump. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--complete-insert`

```
Use complete INSERT statements that include column names.
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_complete-insert

Comment: The --complete-insert does not solve the problem stated above in my original post. It produces a dump file with the same issue presented in the original post.

Comment: Do you want to show or not show the column names?

Comment: Sorry Tan Hong Tat. It works. I did not examine the data properly. Thats what happened when you are a bit frustrated with something, you tend to overlook things. Thanks for the solution man.